# How to replace hard drive in RAID 5 Array and keep data intact?

Tags: raid

How would I go about replacing a defective hard drive in a RAID 5 array while keeping the data intact? I have a Highpoint Rocketraid 2720SGL RAID card.

Comment: Step 1: Remove the old drive. Step 2: Insert the new drive. If the controller doesn't support those two actions then it's really not RAID.

Answer (score 3):

General answer:

Normally, in RAID 5, you pull the broken drive. Then you insert a new drive in its place. Sometimes you have to tell the software to resync after that, but most hardware RAID cards do that just fine on their own.

For your specific card: see page 12 [of the manual](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/PDF/rr2700/RR2720C2/RocketRAID%202720C2%20User%20Manual_v1.00.pdf) in how to add spare drives. Also read the part which says *"Spare Disks
are used to automatically rebuild Redundant RAID arrays"*

Answer (score 1):

I have not used that particular model, but other RAID controller cards from Highpoint.  It should be as simple as removing the bad drive and inserting the new one and from the Rocketraid software telling the array to rebuild.

If you do not have the software installed, or is incompatible with your OS (I know there were some issues with Linux a while back), you can boot to the RAID BIOS and tell it to rebuild from there.